# J_Spring doubts about login problems

Tags: rest, grails

I have the following test of a grails integration:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(loginUrl)
http.request( POST, TEXT ) {
    headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
    send URLENC, [j_username: username, j_password: password]

    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        loggedIn = ! reader.text.contains("j_username")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mount the test in Postman, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because of this send URLENC, [j_username: username, j_password: password]

I put the POST type route, and put something like:

```
{
    j_username: username,
    j_password: password
}
```

And the headers parameters:

```
'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
'Content-type' = 'Application/json'
But it is always returning my login form in the body, does anyone know how to mount this test?
```

UPDATE

Actually in other projects I follow the reference and it works well. However I have developed the grails response part, did not leave an api/login route, and I believe that the login is done by the same web route /login/auth, but I can not validate the test by postman, but on the web logo perfectly.